Blazor .NET 8 - InputSelect: Creating Dropdown from Models
I just followed a course on Blazor .NET 8 from iamtimcorey.com.
I want to create a dropdown form using the InputSelect option from the native form. But I cannot figure out how to populate the dropdown using a column from my model that comes from my SQL database. The example on the course was with a custom list and I cannot fill the gaps with my limited knowledge.
I want to use data from this model:
Models
I have two stored procedures to interact with the database. One of them gets all the data.
The other one gets only two columns: distinct NoFacture (so those numbers do not repeat in the dropdown) and the customer that is linked to that NoFacture (NoFacture means invoice number).
Stored procedures called from Blazor App
Stored procedure result
I want to list all the NoFacture on the dropdown using the GetCommandesToShip() method.
On my Razor component / page, I initialized an empty model I want to fill with the selected NoFacture. But I am unable to fill the InputSelect with my data.
See this screenshot:
Dropdown creation test using Inputselect
I know there is a way to use objects, but I do not have an example and I cannot figure it out.
Here's my code from the Blazor App:
<h1>Expédition / Scanner</h1>

@if (CommandesDetails == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <EditForm Enhance Model="CommandeNoForm" method="post" FormName="noCommandeInput" OnSubmit="SubmitNoCommande">
        <div>
            <br/>
            <label>No de Commande</label>
            <br/>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@CommandesNoForm.NoFacture">
                @foreach (var comm in Enum.GetValues(Commandes.NoFacture))
                {
                    <option value="@comm">@comm.ToString()</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </EditForm>

}

@code {

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private CommandesDetailsModel CommandeNoForm { get; set; } = new();
    private void SubmitNoCommande()
    {
    }

    private IEnumerable<CommandesDetailsModel>? Commandes;
    private IEnumerable<CommandesDetailsModel>? CommandesDetails;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Commandes = await AcombaSql.GetCommandesToShip();
        CommandesDetails = await AcombaSql.GetCommandesDetailsToShip();
    }
}


Here's the code I ended up using and got working:
    <h1>Expédition / Scanner</h1>

@if (Commandes == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    @* <div class="spinner"></div> *@
}
else
{
    <EditForm Enhance Model="CommandeNoForm" method="post" FormName="noCommandeInput" OnSubmit="SubmitNoCommande">
        <div>
            <br/>
            <label>No de Commande</label>
            <br/>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@CommandeNoForm.NoFacture">
                @foreach (var comm in Commandes))
                {
                    <option value="@comm.NoFacture">@comm.NoFacture - @comm.ClientFacturation_NomClient</option>
                }
            </InputSelect>
        </div>
    </EditForm>



}


@code {

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    private CommandesDetailsModel CommandeNoForm { get; set; } = new();
    private void SubmitNoCommande()
    {

    }

    private IList<CommandesDetailsModel>? Commandes;
    private IList<CommandesDetailsModel>? CommandesDetails;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Commandes = (await AcombaSql.GetCommandesToShip()).ToList();
        CommandesDetails = (await AcombaSql.GetCommandesDetailsToShip()).ToList();
    }

}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

As it's difficult to piece together a working example based on your code, I've created a demo.
First a custom component based on InputSelect:
BlazrInputSelect
@*
/// ============================================================
/// Author: Shaun Curtis, Cold Elm Coders
/// License: Use And Donate
/// If you use it, donate something to a charity somewhere
/// ============================================================
*@

@using System.Linq.Expressions
@typeparam TValue
@typeparam TListItem

<InputSelect @attributes=AdditionalAttributes
             TValue="TValue"
             Value=this.Value
             ValueChanged=this.OnChange
             ValueExpression=this.ValueExpression>

    @if (this.Value is null)
    {
        <option selected disabled>@this.PlaceholderText</option>
    }

    @foreach (var option in this.DisplayOptionsItems)
    {
        <option value="@(this.OptionValueDelegate(option))">@(this.OptionTextDelegate(option))</option>
    }

</InputSelect>

@code {
    [Parameter] public TValue? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TValue?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public IEnumerable<TListItem> DisplayOptionsItems { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string> OptionValueDelegate { get; set; } = default!;
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Func<TListItem, string> OptionTextDelegate { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public string PlaceholderText { get; set; } = " -- Select an Option -- ";
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)] public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Check we have a Options list if not throw an exception before we try and render a null list
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.DisplayOptionsItems);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionValueDelegate);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(this.OptionTextDelegate);
    }

    private Task OnChange(TValue value)
        => this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}

And then a demo page to demonstrate how to use it:
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<BlazrInputSelect class="form-select"
                  DisplayOptionsItems="_countries"
                  OptionTextDelegate="(x) => x.Name"
                  OptionValueDelegate="(x) => x.Id.ToString()"
                  TValue="Guid?"
                  TListItem="Country"
                  @bind-Value="_selectedCountryId" />

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    <pre>@_selectedCountry</pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Guid? _selectedCountryId;

    private string _selectedCountry => _countries.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == _selectedCountryId)?.Name ?? "NoneSelected";

    public record Country(Guid Id, string Name, string Code);

    private List<Country> _countries = new()
    {
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "United Kingdom", "GB"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "France", "F"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Spain", "E"),
        new(Guid.NewGuid(), "Portugal", "P"),
    };
}

You should be able to adapt this to fit your context.
